# cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, nsmutabledictionary

It was working fine before but somehow i am getting above error now while converting `NSData to String`. **It showing me error on line number 2** i.e

```
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
```

It shows me error.

> cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

OR

> cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion

```
do{
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
        print("json array string best json request body = \(jsonString)")
        return jsonString

    } catch _ {
        print ("UH OOO")
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Too much `NS` and too much `as`, just use the native Swift structs

```
jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Finally, a helpful answer to my problem! Thanks